# Date Range Validation in GridView asp .net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have two Columns namely Start Date and End Date in my GridView.
I am using Ajax's CalendarExtender for them in ItemTemplate section.

So, what is the best way to validate that start date should not be greater than end date . Now on each selection change by any of the control validation should prompts user on invalid vales.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to hook up the Javascript function to calendar Extender. The event is OnClientDateSelectionChanged = "CheckDate" and use Microsoft AJAX to find other control.
You can apply this to every calendar extender in Gridview DataBound event.

```
function CheckDate(sender, args)
        {
           var Calendar_EndDate = $find(EndDateCalendarExtender.ClientID);
           Calendar_EndDate._startDate = sender._selectedDate;
        }
```

Hope it helps.